# Asymptotic stability of the zero solution of the equation $x'=x/(1+t)-x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

#### Problem

Prove the zero solution of the following equation is asymptotically stable
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x}{1+t}-x^3$$

#### Progress

1. The equation is nonlinear and  non-autonomous.
2. Without the nonlinear term $x^3$ we have a separable equation which is easy to solve: $x(t) = A(1+t)$ for any constant $A$. These solutions are **not** stable; if $A\ne 0$, they move away from the equilibrium solution. Therefore, the nonlinear term is essential for stability; but it makes the equation difficult to solve explicitly. How to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you have tried and your thoughts on the problem? Have you found the critical points and are you familiar with phase portraits? Can you solve the DEQ and investigate it? Knowing your thoughts and attempts helps us to provide better guidance. Regards

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473815/stability-of-a-linear-system).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $V = \dfrac{1}{2}x^2$. Then, $\dfrac{dV}{dt} = x\dfrac{dx}{dt} = \dfrac{x^2}{1+t}-x^4 < 0$ if $|x| > \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}$.

What does this tell you about $x(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bernoulli ODE. Method of solving : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDifferentialEquation.html

[image]