# Lyapunov's stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working on the following differential equations:
$$\frac{dN}{dt} = wN(1-\frac{N}{p})$$
$$\frac{dK}{dt} = sK - gKN$$

where $w, p, s, g$ are real numbers $\ge 0$ and $N, K$ are always positive (or equal $0$).

I'm trying to find equilibrium points and check if they are stable.

My attempt:

I know 3 types of equilibrium points (N,K): $ (0,0), (p,0), (p, K)$ (in the last one, $K$ is any real number $>0$ and $N = p = \frac{s}{g}$).

For the point (0,0) and point (p,0) (if $p \ne \frac{s}{g} $) it's easy to check from linearity. I was able to do that.

But I'm struggling with points $(p,K)$, where $K \ge 0$ and $N = p = \frac{s}{g}$. I tried to find maybe some Lyapunov function, or "antiLyapunov" function, but didn't succeed. I only know that it is not asymptotically stable (some real parts of eigenvalues from linearity are equal to $0$), but what about Lyapunov's stability? Can you help and show me how to check it? I've spent a lot of time on it, but can't get any results...

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473815/stability-of-a-linear-system).

Comment: But there they use Jacobi matrix, which is useless in my case- the real part of at least one eigenvalue is zero, so I can't say anything about Lyapunov's stability.

Comment: Perhaps linearisation of the system around the equilibrium  points may help.

Comment: @Anne: You need to look in the literature.